# How to open windows command prompt and enter or pass commands using python code?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to open the windows command prompt and pass some simple commands as below.

1. Open windows command prompt
2. and type "ls -l"

I wanted to automate the above steps

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,create a file 'file1.py' and put below code into it.

```
import os
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"ls -l; exec bash\"'")
```

and run 'python file1.py'